# How can I access Chrome's user metrics?

Tags: google-chrome, tracking

Chrome records certain user actions, for example (see [here](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/ui/browser_commands.cc) for full source):

```
content::RecordAction(UserMetricsAction("NewIncognitoWindow"));
```

Is there a way I can access my Chrome user metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing `chrome://stats`. If it doesn't load, run chrome from the command line like this:

`Chrome.exe --enable-stats-table`

Source: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/e4L14lBF4j8

You can find more interesting pages here: http://lifehacker.com/5045164/google-chromes-full-list-of-special-about-pages

Answer (score 1):

`chrome://stats` is no longer available. Using `chrome://ukm` may be helpful. It can be invoked by:

`chrome.exe --force-enable-metrics-reporting`